# Крово- и слёзопролитная война

Tags: прилагательные, существительные, conjunctions

Как я должен говорить и писать:

*Это была крово- и слёзопролитная война*

*Это была крово и слёзопролитная война*

*Это была крово-и-слёзопролитная война*

*Это была крово и слёзопролитная война*

Comment: а какой вариант кажется вам предпочительны и почему остальный кажутся не правильными / менее предпочтительными?

Comment: also, keep in mind that cross-posting (as happened with this particular question) is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Изначально я написал так, как написано в первой строке. Потом подумал, что, возможно, дефис не нужен. Засомневался, выдумал остальные потом ещё. А так думаю, что первый как раз-таки самый лучший.

Comment: Well, I made a duplicate only because a week or around it ago I asked something else and I've been still waiting for the answer!!! This way I just doubled my chances to get more reviews and maybe get the answer I need right now but not in a week, month, year etc.

Comment: Варианты 2 и 4 совпадают.

Comment: Водо- и пыленепроницаемость. Верен первый вариант. Только есть одна тонкость. Выражения типа "иксо- и игрекозетная вещь" уместны, если икс и игрек равноценны.  А слезопролитная — это что-то из одного ряда с выражением "слезоточивая мелодрама"

Comment: Это была настоящая война, крово- и слезопролитная, целые армии нервных клеток были уничтожены и покалечены! Правда, победителей здесь не случилось - Первое, что гуглится на "слезопролитная". Но , скорее всего, это неологизм.

Comment: Тут тоже downvоting? Интересно.

Comment: "слёзопролитная" - такого слова в русском языке просто нет.

Answer (score 2):

Верен 1 вариант: `это была крово- и слёзопролитная война` (если считать, что есть слово "слёзопролитный").

[С сайта orfogrammka.ru](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0/)

> Единственный случай, когда после дефиса ставится пробел — когда ко
> второй части составного слова по очереди подставляются две первые
> части. Например: радио-, теле- и видеоспектакли.

Answer (score 2):

Точно такой же вопрос (точно тем же участником) задавался на сайте «Русский язык».

Я его [вопрос] откорректировала, поменяла метки и дала ответ (предоставляю ссылку, чтобы не «ползать» по сайтам; можно посмотреть и оценивание, и комментарии):
[Крово- и слёзопролитный](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462826/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Если ***абстрагироваться*** от значения особенного слова (слёзопролитный), то предложение необходимо оформить с так называемым висячим дефисом:
**Это была крово- и слёзопролитная война.**

Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим», например:
*шарико- и роликоподшипники; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы; как водо-, так и газоснабжение; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты; до- или послеперестроечные процессы.*
[Дефис (§ 112)](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59)

*Крово/пролитный* и *слёзо/пролитный* — общим конечным элементом сложных слов является "пролитный" (его и отделяем).

Но дело в том, что в словарях нет такого слова — слёзопролитная (слёзопролитный).
С конечным элементом "пролитный" имеется всего лишь одно слово, зафиксированное словарями, — [кровопролитный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (сопровождающийся пролитием большого количества крови).

В толковом словаре:
[проли́ть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
**3.** *что.* Заставить течь, струиться (обычно напоказ). ***Пролить слезу** (ирон.*; поплакать). *Пролить пот* (усердно, напряжённо потрудиться). ***Пролить (чью-либо) кровь*** (убить, ранить кого-либо). ***Пролить (свою) кровь** за кого-либо, что-либо (высок.*; пожертвовать жизнью или оказаться раненным, защищая кого-либо, что-либо).

Если Вы хотите употребить слово "слёзопролитный" в серьезном тексте (без иронии, издёвки, насмешки), я бы не рекомендовала Вам использовать этот неологизм.

**Дополнение-разъяснение**
Дело в том, что проблема здесь не в *пробеле* после дефиса (между словами пробел, конечно же, необходим), а собственно в правильном использовании **висячего дефиса.**
И ещё: на процесс *говорения* эти правильно или неправильно поставленные дефисы никак не влияют — они отображаются только в орфографии, то есть *в написании.*